# Error while opening JDBC connection from Weblogic server 10.3.5

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, deployment, oracle-adf

I developed an ADF application in Jdeveloper11.1.1.7 and deployed it in Weblogic server 10.3.5. From Jdeveloper every thing working perfectly But from weblogic server I can see in the server stack the error (`Error while opening JDBC connection, Caused by null password given; logon denied`)  here is part of exception thrown:

```
Exception inside -------.jbo.DMLException: JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC connection.
oracle.jbo.DMLException: JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC connection.
        at oracle.jbo.server.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:207)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ConnectionPool.instantiateResource(ConnectionPool.java:166)
        at oracle.jbo.pool.ResourcePool.createResource(ResourcePool.java:583)
        at oracle.jbo.pool.ResourcePool.useResource(ResourcePool.java:316)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ConnectionPool.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionPool.java:102)
        at oracle.jbo.server.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:67)
        .......................................
        .......................................
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
```

I did what is suggested in the following links:

[My Learning's @ Work - by Lakshmipathi Kakarla: ORA-01005: null password given](http://www.lkakarla.com/2013/11/ora-01005-null-password-given.html)

[Extending WebLogic Server for ADF Applications](http://radalcove.com/blog/?p=34) Step 23

I added `Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true` to the `JAVA_PROPERTIES` and `EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES` and restart the server but the issue is not resolved. Any idea what goes wrong? Please note that the file (`setDomainEnv`) in the `bin` folder for the weblogic domain contains more that setting to the previous variables, the  change I did is always rise in the first set of the variables

Attached where exactly the command is added in `setDomainEnv` is it the right place to add? what is missing?

[image: setDomainEnv source file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this link:

[Error while opening JDBC connection from Weblogic server 10.3.5](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3595349)

problem solved by changing application module configuration form using JDBC URL to using DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error:

```
oracle.jbo.DMLException: JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC connection.
```

Went [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1069535), said to alter AppModule configuration. So... right click on AppModule->Configurations->Edit

Connection Type for me was set to "JDBC Datasource". I set it to "JDBC URL". Note:

For some reason the JDBC URL may have to be tweaked. Here's mine:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=FULLY_QUALIFIED_HOST)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=ORACLE_SID)(server=DEDICATED)))
```

It worked. On to the real problem.